# How to insert data from a jsp page into mysql database and run queries on that table , from inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, phpmyadmin

I have the following `JDBC` connection with mysql database :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String string = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(string , "root2" , "root");
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from names"); // SELECT * FROM `names`
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next())
        {
            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + " " + result.getString(2));
        }


    }
}
```

When I go into `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and create a database , I can run successfully queries on the database the I made there , but how can I do that from inside `Eclipse` (e.g java) ?

To be more clear, the user enters data into a `jsp` page , and I extract the data 
from there . After that , I want to create a database from inside Eclipse , without going directly into `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` . How can I do that ?

**EDIT:**

I have the needed servlets , what I want now is to create the database from the servlet and run the queries from the servlet .

Thanks

Comment: It is better to avoid java code in JSP (Scriptlets) in all possible cases. You may need to consider adding servlet and just copy the code you have in above class to there.

Comment: You want to create a database dynamically ?

Comment: @thinksteep: I have a servlet , my question is how to create the database from the servlet and run that with the jdbc .

Comment: did you try : executeQuery("create database mydatabase"); ? But why do you want to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete answer to your question will require a lot of writing and few clarifications.

There is excellent tutorial which you can use: 
[Creating Database Web Applications with Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html)

Instead of Derby DB you will use MySQL.